# Trig substitutions. What is going on?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I am a bit confused about my book's explanation regarding trig substitutions. I understand u-subs... but I don't get this:

[image]

first where did the equation $x = a \sin\theta$ come from? What is x here? What does a represent?

Comment: keep in mind that "trigonometric substitution" is really a misnomer. In this case, we're actually making an "inverse trigonometric" substitution. i.e. $x=a\sin\theta$ is equivalent to $\theta = \sin^{-1} \frac{x}{a}$.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to compute $$\int \sqrt{1-x^2}dx.$$ Notice that if $x$ were nice and looked like $\sin t$, then the root would conveniently disappear since $$\sqrt{1-x^2} = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 t} = \sqrt{\cos^2 t} = \cos t,$$ so substitution $x = \sin t$ makes such an integral much easier to handle.

---

In a more general case, where you want to find $$\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$$ for some fixed positive real number $a$, the trick is to represent $x$ in such a form as to factor $a$ outside of the root, allowing us to do a similar trick as before. So we let $x = a\sin t$, to get
$$
\sqrt{a^2-x^2}
 = \sqrt{a^2 - (a\sin t)^2}
 = \sqrt{a^2 - a^2 \sin^2 t}
 = a \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 t}
 = a \cos t.
$$

Comment: Oh so we're doing a usub using trig? Is a just a constant?

Comment: @Jwan622 yes, correct -- this is the basic example of a trigonometric substitution with $a$ being a real positive constant.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem
$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(g(x)) g'(x) dx$$
(with the appropriate hypotheses) has various names. When used in the specific direction of right-to-left in one dimension, it's usually called *$u$-substitution* (and one usually uses $u$ instead of $x$ as the variable of integration).

However, the other direction, left-to-right, is just as useful. For special instances of $g$, this result is called various things. If $g$ is a trigonometric function, such as $\sin$, $\cos$, or $\tan$, this may be called *trigonometric substitution*. If $h$ is a hyperbolic function, such as $\sinh$, $\cosh$, or $\tanh$, it may be called *hyperbolic substitution*. On the whole however, the left-to-right direction (or both directions together) is often called *change of variables*---especially in higher dimensions.